# bootstrap modal delete button is working but not return back from controller succesfully

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

**I have Bootstrap modal in View.**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                    <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Sil
                </button>
                <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Düzenle
                </button>
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script for delete button.**

```
   $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Planner/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

**And This is controller for delete operation**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
{
    var status = false;
    using (eteklifn_netEntities dc = new eteklifn_netEntities())
    {
        var v = dc.TBLEVENTS.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != null)
        {
            dc.TBLEVENTS.Remove(v);
            dc.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}
```

> When click the event, the modal opens. When click the btnDelete button event id  goes to DeleteEvent Controller. Controller deletes succesfully event from database and return status= true. But still fail alert works. and in a way I do not understand page refresh.

Comment: can u try with return Json(status) ? it must send a true for javascript evaluation. if not make a console.log(data) before if (data.status) , to evaluate what information is coming exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this code.

$('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Planner/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response == "DeleteSucceeded") {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

//in your controller method try this

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
    {
        var status = false;
        var v = dc.TBLEVENTS.Where(a => a.EventID == eventID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (v != null)
        {
            using (eteklifn_netEntities dc = new eteklifn_netEntities())
            {
                dc.TBLEVENTS.Remove(v);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
            return Json("DeleteSucceeded");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("DeleteFailed");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is something else. There was a form tag in layout class. and it was overlapping with the other form.